# Empty Git submodule folder when repo cloned

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules, git-clone

I have one repo hosted at https://github.com/aikiframework/json. On my local copy, I added a submodule using the command:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:jcubic/json-rpc.git json-rpc
```

Then I did a commit and push, and the changes appear on GitHub (I can click on it). But when I clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/aikiframework/json.git
```

the submodule folder `json-rpc` is empty.

What am I missing here? Did I forget about something? Why is that folder empty?

Comment: if you forgot the `--recursive` flag in your git clone then you can do `git submodule update --init`

Comment: @CharlieParker it's in accepted answer first comment.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

OK I found it, needed to add `--recursive` when cloning the repo.

So the clone command ends up as:

```
git clone https://github.com/aikiframework/json.git --recursive
```

Note that if you forgot the `--recursive` flag you can do (thanks to @Amber):

```
git submodule update --init
```

Note that when submodules have other submodules you need recursive option (thanks for @cpprust):

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Yep. You can also fetch submodules after the fact with `git submodule update --init`, if you already cloned but forgot `--recursive`.

Comment: Just faced the problem that there is a submodule on develop branch, but not yet on the master branch. When you clone the git repo using --recursive it will not find the submodule on the master branch, and you have to fetch it using Ambers comment "git submodule update --init" to get also the subomdule.

Comment: If you use `git submodule update --init` you will have to go to each repo and do `git checkout master` otherwise you'll get error `You are not currently on a branch.` on `git pull` when you try to update it to a newer version.

Comment: @Noitidart is there a way that doesn't do that? (after cloning the project already)

Comment: @borgr i couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for the `update --init` hint. That does help when original clone didn't have `--recursive` in it and simply wanting to pull the missing submodules.

Comment: Thanks for that note @JariTurkia - I didn't know I needed that because I had forgot `--recursive`.

Comment: I think it should be `git submodule update --init --recursive` since submodule can have their submodules too. (e.g. [pytorch/third_party](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/main/third_party)/kineto, [kineto/libkineto/third_party](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/tree/main/libkineto/third_party))

Comment: @cpprust adding your tip to the answer, thanks for improving it.