# How to update a submodule to latest commit when in detached HEAD state?

Tags: git

I am trying to update my submodules so that they use a more recent commit.

When we use submodules, they are supposed to remain in a detached head state.  That's fine.

```
$ cd myproject
$ cd otherlibrary
$ git status .
HEAD detached from 091eccc
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I did some work in `otherlibrary` and now I'd like to update `myproject` so that it will use these new commits in `otherlibrary`.  That means, I need to 'update the submodule' somehow.

This doesn't work: (see? it's still has the same commit number)

```
$ cd myproject
$ cd otherlibrary
$ git submodule update --remote
$ git status .
HEAD detached from 091eccc
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

For completeness, I also tried it like this `git submodule update --rebase --remote` and like this `git submodule update --merge --remote` and that doesn't make any difference.

I also read these two SO articles that talk about the subject, but my problem isn't solved by this:

- [Update a submodule to the latest commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191299/update-a-submodule-to-the-latest-commit)
- [Git submodule detached head state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555375/git-submodule-detached-head-state)

Comment: In what way `git submodule update --remote` doesn't help?

Comment: Well, ignoring every other fact and only caring about the end result, the result is that whatever is now in the `otherlibrary` folder after that command, is still not the most recent code.

Comment: `git submodule update --remote` must be run from the superproject: `cd myproject` but not `cd otherlibrary`

Comment: Ok that works.  But how do I update just `otherlibrary` in a situation where I have 10 submodules?

Comment: `git submodule update --remote otherlibrary && git add otherlibrary && git commit -m "Update otherlibrary"`. Or `cd otherlibrary && git checkout master && git pull && cd .. && git add otherlibrary && git commit -m "Update otherlibrary"`

Answer (score 3):

As [phd noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705003/how-to-update-a-submodule-to-latest-commit-when-in-detached-head-state#comment105565598_59705003), to use `git submodule update`, you must be *in the superproject*.

(All `git submodule update --remote` does is `cd` into the submodule, run a `git fetch`, and then run a `git checkout`, so if you don't want to pop back up to the superproject for some reason, you can run the `git fetch` and `git checkout` yourself.  If you do this, you can poke around in the fetch results and carefully choose the specific commit you'd like, rather than just taking the one identified by `origin/master` or whatever.  Of course, if the one you'd like *is* whichever one is identified by `origin/master`, the `git submodule update --remote` is convenient.)

Comment: What if I have 10 `otherprojects` and I don't want them all updated?

Comment: In that case, you can either limit the `git submodule` command to one specific submodule, or—my preferred method—just `cd` into the submodule yourself and work there until satisfied.